# Ajax like/unlike button with rails4 90% working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a few models that can be liked/unliked. I have a button now and everything works perfectly, except that page used to have to reload everytime.

I now have it as an ajax button and it POST the data fine. BUT the problem is it seems a little hacked together.

If the post is NOT liked when the page loads, you click like, and the heart turns red and the label says liked. If you click the button again, it unlikes the post but to button label and color wont change. The problem is that if you keep clicking the button it will keep POSTing the unlike data even though it is already unliked. The opposite is true if the post is liked when the page loads. It keeps posting the like data. I have an activity feed so it post the same activity a crap load of times.

Here is the code I have;

## statuses controller

```
def upvote
  @status = Status.find(params[:id])
  current_user.create_activity(@status, 'liked')
  @status.liked_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to statuses_path }
    format.json { render json: @status }
   end
end

def downvote
  @status = Status.find(params[:id])
  @activity = Activity.find_by(targetable_id: @status)
  @activity.destroy!
  @status.downvote_from current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to statuses_path }
    format.json { render json: @status}
  end
end
```

## Application JS

```
$("#view-heart").click(function() {
  var id = this.getElementsByTagName('sub')[0].innerHTML

  if ($( "#test" ).hasClass( "red" )) {
    $(this).replaceWith('<span id="view-heart"><a href="' + 
    window.location.href + "/" + id + "/like" + '" action="upvote" data-
    method="put" class="item like-dislike" data-type="json" data-
    remote="true"><i class="fi-heart" id="test"></i><label>Like</label>
    </a></span>');
    $( "#test" ).removeClass( 'red' );
  } else {
    $(this).replaceWith('<span id="view-heart"><a href="' + 
    window.location.href + "/" + id + "/dislike" + '" action="downvote" 
    data-method="put" class="item like-dislike" data-type="json" data-
    remote="true"><i class="fi-heart red" id="test"></i>
    <label>Liked</label></a></span>');
  }
});
```

## Status Index

```
<% if current_user.voted_up_on? status %>
  <span id="view-heart">
    <a href=" <%= "/statuses/"+ status.id.to_s + "/dislike" %>"    
    action="downvote" data-method="put" class="item like-dislike" data-
    type="json" data-remote="true">
      <i class="fi-heart red" id="test"></i>
      <label>Liked</label>
      <sub><%= status.id %></sub>
    </a>
  </span>
  <% else %>
   <span id="view-heart">
     <a href=" <%= "/statuses/"+ status.id.to_s + "/like" %>"    
     action="upvote" data-method="put" class="item like-dislike" data-
     type="json" data-remote="true">
       <i class="fi-heart" id="test"></i>
       <label>Like</label>
       <sub><%= status.id %></sub>
     </a>
   </span>
<% end %>
```

Github project for reference if needed `https://github.com/JaredCowan/GA-Cohort-Network`

Any help to clean this up and fix it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Asking for help fixing code is on-topic for Stack Overflow. Cleaning up code falls out of scope on Stack Overflow and should be something asked about on [codereview.se].

Comment: Who's asking to clean-up code? I ask to help "clean-up" to get the code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this code:

```
$("#view-heart").click(function() {...
```

Binds *one time only* to the *current* `#view-heart` element.

The first time it is clicked, it replaces that element with a new element, and the click binding is not re-established on the new element, so subsequent clicks won't invoke the JavaScript click handler.

There are a few possible solutions to this:

1. Instead of replacing the entire element, the JavaScript code could manipulate the attributes of the existing element. This is probably the simplest solution.
2. Instead of binding the click event directly to the element, you could use jQuery's [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind to a parent element, and match with a selector. This has the effect of creating a "live" event handler that will respond to changes on the page.

   For example:

   ```
   $(document).on("click", "#view-heart", function() {...
   ```

   Other than being responsive to changes in the DOM, this sometimes has performance benefits if there are a lot of matching elements on the page.

You can use both solutions together, too.

Comment: One more thing to be aware of... I don't see the code that actually submits the AJAX post to the server, but consider the possibility that the request could fail (e.g., if the network drops). In that case, the heart might change to red on the client side, but it would not be saved on the back end. Consider changing the element in the success handler instead of on click, or adding code to revert on failure.

Comment: Thank-you this is nice than what I have. but I still couldn't get it to replace. Really weird.

Comment: Can you add your updated code and I can try to see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you have is that, when your .erb file is rendered, the if statement only show one of those code blocks.  So if the post is already liked, the first half of the 'if' statement executes.  This .erb does not reload on every click, so the form that was loaded at page render submits repeatedly. Your javascript just changes the color of '#test'.

Consider getting rid of the 'if' statement in your .erb file, and rendering both forms, then hiding one form based on whether the model is 'liked' or not.  Then hide/unhide each button when they are clicked.  Each button will perform its own individual submit.

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying. But it's not really a form, it's just a button with a class. So when I click the button and replace the html, shouldn't it check if the `DOM` if it has the class `RED` and go from there? The only thing the .erb `IF` statement is doing is when the page loads it gives the button the style.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution to this is to put both of the links in there each time, however, you want to change the stacking order based on whether or not it was voted upon. So if the the post was already liked, the dislike button would thus be on top. If the button is clicked a class would be added to place it behind the like button.

```
<% if current_user.voted_up_on? status %>
  <span id="view-heart">
    <a href=" <%= "/statuses/"+ status.id.to_s + "/dislike" %>"    
action="downvote" data-method="put" class="item like-dislike" data-
type="json" data-remote="true">
         <i class="fi-heart red" id="test"></i>
         <label>Liked</label>
         <sub><%= status.id %></sub>
    </a>
    <a href=" <%= "/statuses/"+ status.id.to_s + "/like" %>"    
     action="upvote" data-method="put" class="item like-dislike" data-
     type="json" data-remote="true">
        <i class="fi-heart" id="test"></i>
        <label>Like</label>
        <sub><%= status.id %></sub>
     </a>
</span>
<% else %>
   <span id="view-heart">
     <a href=" <%= "/statuses/"+ status.id.to_s + "/like" %>"    
     action="upvote" data-method="put" class="item like-dislike" data-
     type="json" data-remote="true">
        <i class="fi-heart" id="test"></i>
        <label>Like</label>
        <sub><%= status.id %></sub>
     </a>
     <a href=" <%= "/statuses/"+ status.id.to_s + "/dislike" %>"    
     action="downvote" data-method="put" class="item like-dislike" data-
     type="json" data-remote="true">
         <i class="fi-heart red" id="test"></i>
         <label>Liked</label>
         <sub><%= status.id %></sub>
    </a>
   </span>
<% end %>
```

This now becomes an easy jquery solution of adding and removing classes to show one or the other based on which was clicked